# webGL alternatives on Android

Tags: java, javascript, android, webkit, webgl

As Android WebKit does not natively support webGL yet (true?) I am looking forward to emulate webGL in an embedded WebKit app.

Are there any bindings which would expose OpenGL ES Java interfaces to Javascript in a manner it could be even close to webGL?

Answer (score 2):

FYI: Firefox for Android does support WebGL. It's not the fastest, but it does work.

Answer (score 0):

Not quite what you're looking for, but maybe this could help you: http://processingjs.org/

It's ProcessingJS, based on processing (http://processing.org/).

Answer (score 0):

You could expose OpenGL ES 2.0 (Note that WebGL is a subset of OpenGL ES 2.0) methods to javascript via:

```
WebView.addJavascriptInterface(Object, String);
```

It will be slower than a native app, but you could emulate almost every WebGL call there.

Quick Edit: I was trying to do the same but preferred to do a native version.