# Porting WebGL game to iPhone's native OpenGL?

Tags: iphone, ios, html, opengl-es, webgl

We are developing a web game that uses WebGL for the two biggest parts of it. Working with HTML / CSS was too slow and too limited, so it's off the table.

Thing is, iOS does not support WebGL publicly just yet, only on iAd. It is my guess Apple will eventually support it once the security issues they and Microsoft claim it has are fixed, and looks stable enough.

Problem is, if Apple does not do this by the release of the next mayor iOS version, then we will have in our hands a mobile WebGL game that does not run. 6 months of development and testing to waste.

**So, questions:**

- If that was the case, how viable (regarding amount of time) is it porting the WebGL part of the game to native iPhone OpenGL? I'm afraid that porting will take longer than the development of the game itself.
- I saw posts on Stack Overflow ([like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8267282/webgl-alternatives-on-android)) that suggested, on Android, adding the OpenGL interface manually to a WebKit element. It'd be slower than native. But either way... Is this something that could be accepted in the AppStore? Apple is very restrictive with these kind of stuff...

Thank you all for your time!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd say it takes 2-3 months to port, with the lack of input data in the question. Of course if this means learning Obj-C simultaneously it will be some uphill battle.

OpenGL is all the same in every run-time, so porting should be straightforward, or even running JS in the context of a native app.

Apple doesnt care what you submit to App Store as long as it works.

Comment: Yeah, Apple does care a lot =/ but that is good to know. Someone else would be joining the team in that case, someone who already knows Obj-C. Uhm... is it possible really to run the same JS code for the native app?

Comment: You can run JS either through WebKit or using your own JS run-time engine. My strategy would be latter and try to run JS engine using your own interpreter and having native bindings to do all the OpenGL stuff. At least Appcelerator had somekind of custom Javascript run-time but there must be others.